# Search and list person's name in a book with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm not sure whether this task can be solved with machine learning and want to get some suggestions.

I want to search and list all the names of person from a random book (suppose they are all written in lower case). I can manually label a few names in the beginning for training purpose. I guess I can use some supervised learning algorithm, but I don't know what kind of features can be obtained because only available information I can think of in this scenario is the text of the book.

Can you give me a high level suggestion on steps to solve this question with machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

[Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) is pretty well-researched problem.

There are existing libraries solving it, for example this is a [nice tutorial](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition) for Spacy.

Comment: Thank you,it's what exactly I need.